# What's the name of this equation? Please give me some document about it.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image: PDE]

I have a equation. Can someone help me?
 [image]

Comment: Is it $\nabla u$ or $\Delta u$?

Comment: Sorry. I have a mistake. It's $ \triangle u $

Comment: In chemistry, this is the reaction–diffusion–advection equation in its equilibrium state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an inhomogeneous linear elliptic equation with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. If $\mu$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are constant, then then it is said to have constant coefficients.